# java split - problem with space

Tags: java, regex

```
 String[] t = a.slowa("a. R; er,  we p.");
   for (String w : t)
    System.out.println(w);
  }
 //...
  public String[] slowa(String s) {
   return s.split(" |\\.|,|\\;");
  }
```

output:

```
a

R

er


we
p
```

Why spaces are new world?

Comment: *"Why space is new world?"* Say what? Welcome to StackOverflow. The more effort you put into making your questions clear and specific, the more and better answers you'll receive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've told the `String#split` function to split on a space **or** a dot **or** a comma **or** a semicolon. So that's what it's done:

```
"a. R; er,  we p."
  ^^ ^^  ^^^  ^ ^
  || ||  |||  | |
  || ||  |||  | +--Split here
  || ||  |||  +----And here
  || ||  ||+-------And here
  || ||  |+--------And here
  || ||  +---------And here
  || |+------------And here
  || +-------------And here
  |+---------------And here
  +----------------And here
```

...because you've used an alternation with no quantifier. What you want is to say split on *any* of these:

```
return s.split("[ .,;]+");
```

That uses a character class (`[...]`) and a quanitifier (`+`) so that more than one in a row is treated as a single match. You could also do it with an alternation+quantifier (you have to wrap the alternation in a non-capturing group: `"(?: |\\.|,|\\;)+"`), but using a character class is cleaner.